# Problems with Qt5 quick qml test and opengl rendering

Tags: windows, opengl, rendering, qt

I am trying to run a .qml testcase that renders a UI window but I don't have opengl in my windows docker container. My test case will hang and I get the following output when trying to run my test case:

```
qt.scengraph.general: Loading backend software
Test "tst_page1.qml" window not shown().
Test "tst_page1.qml" window was never exposed! If the test case was expecting windowShown, it will hang.
```

I have the environment variables set:

```
set QT_OPENGL=software
set QT_QUICK_BACKEND=software
set QML_SCENE_DEVICE=softwarecontext
```

I believe that these settings will allow me to run an openglsw version of opengl for rendering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using `headless rendering`. With Qt5, you can pass an argument with your executable call to use offscreen rendering.

```
myProg.exe -platform offscreen
```